# Connecting Outlook to Unix mail server

Tags: postfix, ldap, dovecot, outlook, opendirectory

I notice that i am unable to connect Outlook (2013) users with my Unix mail server. I have tried from a remote computer and localhost at my local network with Mail App and its working fine except with Outlook where i cannot find a way to connect it. I have also a web mail service at my mail server and this working fine too.

In my server i am using:

- Postfix
- Dovecot
- Getmail
- Server App
- Open Directory (LDAP)
- Mail password types allowed: CRAM-MD5, Digest-MD5, GSSAPI

I am getting this error when i try to connect through outlook:

> Iniciating session in the reception server of mail (IMAP): Failure
>   with general authentication. No one of those authentication methods
>   are supported by the IMAP server (if exists) are supported by this
>   computer.

It seems that i am having a problem with user authentication with Outlook and i dont know well how to solve it, because all my users are set to just use Open Directory.

In dovecot: auth_mechanisms = digest-md5 cram-md5 gssapi. Through telnet to port 143 i have also AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=GSSAPI. I was using the same settings as i was through Mail app, login username and password, and the DNS name of this mail server through IMAP.

Is there a way to set up Outlook to login in an user password type of Open Directory?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE1:

I have already add 'plain' for authentication for postfix and dovecot, and still nothing, same error. I believe that this is occurring because i have set my users to use an Open Directory and i cannot use other types of passwords, i am stick to digest-md5 cram-md5 gssapi.

UPDATE2:

Postfix:

```
smtpd_pw_server_security_options = cram-md5,digest-md5,gssapi, plain
```

Dovecot (10-auth.conf):

```
auth_mechanisms = digest-md5 cram-md5 gssapi plain
disable_plaintext_auth = no
```

Sill same error.

With POP3 i have an error description a bit bigger:

```
-ERR [AUTH] Plaintext authentication disallowed on non-secure (SSL/TLS) connections
```

At least with TLS, i have it activated in postfix, with CA's,

```
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_enforce_tls = no
smtpd_tls_CAfile = ...
smtpd_tls_key_file = ...
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = SSLv2, aNULL, ADH, eNULL
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

So there is a way to enable this authentications for Outlook?

Comment: pop3 enabled on the server ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply yagmoth555! I have already tested and same result, it seems that Outlook can only authenticate with plain, it gives me an error about plain authentication. I have postfix and dovecot allowing plain, but i must have the directory of each user allowing that type of password too, because each user have a storage in the server that can be only accessed through Open Directory passwords. I think that this is the problem but i am not sure.

Comment: The error from POP3 in the client Outlook: -ERR [AUTH] Plaintext authentication disallowed on non-secure (SSL/TLS) connections (also i have TLS activated and CA's in postfix: smtpd_use_tls = yes)

Comment: Have a look at `doveconf -n` and make sure the options are really applied. Configure `auth_verbose=yes` and `auth_debug=yes` to get further understanding what happens behind the scenes.